# Continuity of piecewise function using limits

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am stuck on this calculus question. I have a piecewise function as follows:

$f(x) = 1/(x+2), \quad x \neq -2$
or

$f(x) = 1, \quad x = -2$

The question is if this function is continuous at $x = -2$. I believe it is, but I have to prove using LHS and RHS limits, which I am not too sure how to do.
Wouldn't both limits in this case approaching -2 from the left side and right side both equal 1?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think this limit exists and equal to 1? Try to plot the function to get some intuition

Comment: Oh. Okay, upon plotting it, I see now that approaching -2 from the left hand side, the function diverges to negative infinity, and approaching -2 from the right-hand side the function diverges to positive infinity. Therefore, the function is discontinuous at x = -2. That is strange, because it is defined at x = -2!

Comment: Why is it strange? The fact that a function is defined doesn't imply it is continuous, and if that were the case, there wasn't any motivation defining a new term 'continuous' :)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Tip for writing math: if you want to write a fraction, you can use the \frac{}{} option. for example, \frac{x^2}{y+5} = $\frac{x^2}{y+5}$

Comment: Ah. yes, I will remember that for the future.